# Validate MVC5 Captcha

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am adding a captcha on the MVC5 form and submitting to form using Ajax. In the controller the this.IsCaptchaValid() method is always returning "false".
Please let me know how can I validate the captcha while submitting the form using Ajax call. I am using CaptchaMVC5 with below code.

```
<div>
@Html.Captcha(3)
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="submit()" />
</div>
<script language="javascript">
function submit() {

    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "POST",
        data: { formdata: formData },        
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller Action Method:

```
[HttpPost, CaptchaVerify("Captcha is not valid")]
public ActionResult Index(Registration Registration)
{
    // Code for validating the Captcha
    if (this.IsCaptchaValid("Validate captcha"))
    {
         ViewBag.ErrMessage = "Validation Messgae";
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue and just serialized the form as a data. Actually I didn't send it as json object and it works for me.

```
function submit() {

    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('form').serialize(),        
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
}
```

hope it helps.